# XSD Schema with unique id as attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, unique-index

I want to write a XSD Schema for the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<siss-statusquery xmlns="http://www.example.de/test">
    <myhash id="1">DG5F6DFG13DFG5641DG5F6DFG13DFG56411337AS</myhash>
    <myhash id="2">123AWDFG13DFG5641DG5F6DFG13GFG56411337AS</myhash>
    <myhash id="3">DG5F6DFG13DFG5641DG5F6325DFG13DFG5641143</myhash>
</siss-statusquery>
```

Conditions:

- `<myhash />` tag, minoccurs: `1` , maxoccurs: `unbounded`
- `id` attribute, type: `unsignedInt`, is `unique`, is `required`
- `<myhash />` tag value pattern: `[0-9A-Z]{40,40}`

My attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.example.de/test" 
           xmlns:lhs="http://www.example.de/test">

  <xs:simpleType name="myhashType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-Z]{40,40}" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="siss-statusquery">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="myhash"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded"
                    minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="lhs:myhashType">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:unsignedInt" name="id" use="required" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

How can I constrict/restrict the `id` attribute as unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML Schema has a type for globally unique IDs - `xs:ID` - but you can't use that here because values of this type have to be valid XML names (so in particular they can't start with a digit).

The way to apply more general uniqueness constraints is to use `xs:unique`:

```
<xs:element name="siss-statusquery">
    <xs:complexType>
       <!-- as before -->
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniqueId">
        <xs:selector xpath="lhs:myhash" />
        <xs:field xpath="@id" />
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

The way to read this is that within the scope of the containing element, all the elements matched by the `selector` must have different values for their `field`.  So in this case, within the `siss-statusquery`, all the `myhash` elements must have different `id` attributes.

Comment: Is there any way this can be generalised? For instance if I have a bunch of elements with different names, but they all require unique integer ids, is there a way of having this at a common location rather than having to specify it for each element? <xs:unique> can only go inside an <xs:element>...

Comment: Have just realised I can use "./ElementName1 | ./ElementName2" etc in the xpath :)